# C# XML Serialization XMLElement without tag

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeModel
{
    [XmlElement("CustomerName")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("")]
    public int CustomerAge { get; set; }
}
```

Which (when populated with some test data) and Serialized using XmlSerializer.Serialize() results in the following XML:

```
<SomeModel>
  <CustomerName>John</CustomerName>
  <CustomerAge>55</CustomerAge>
</SomeModel>
```

What I need to have is:

```
<SomeModel>
  <CustomerName>John</CustomerName>
   55
</SomeModel>
```

Meaning for the 2nd xmlelement, it should not have its own tag. Is this even possible? Thank you.

Comment: Why you want do that? When you convert back this xml to class SameModel it will be without CustomerAge.

Comment: The API that my app is using demands this XML structure

Comment: Have you tried `[XmlText]`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504150/serialize-a-c-sharp-class-to-xml-with-attributes-and-a-single-value-for-the-clas

Comment: [Serializable] is unnecessary with XmlSerializer. It is used to instruct BinaryFormatter.

Comment: Thanks, but I hit "There was an error reflecting type" when serializing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decorate `CustomerAge` with [XmlText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) instead of `XmlElement`.

You'll also have to change the type of `CustomerAge` from `int` to `string` and If you don't want to, you'll have to take an extra property for serialization like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [XmlElement("CustomerName")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string CustomerAgeString { get { return CustomerAge.ToString(); } set { throw new NotSupportedException("Setting the CustomerAgeString property is not supported"); } }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string CustomerAge { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I hit "There was an error reflecting type" when serializing

Comment: Is it possible for you to Change type of CustomerAge to String from int?

Comment: Thanks so much! You're a lifesaver!