# soap complex type array item value

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a wsdl. I referenced and run it. I can see item value in fiddler.

response:

```
        <ns1:Results>
            <ns1:Result>
                <ns1:Status>true</ns1:Status>
                <ns1:Message>Başarılı</ns1:Message>
                <ns1:VendorAccount/>
                <ns1:DeliveryNumberList>
                    <ns1:DeliveryNumber PackingSlipNo="X100327233" VendorAccount="0002230728" Vat="">008740774</ns1:DeliveryNumber>
                </ns1:DeliveryNumberList>
            </ns1:Result>
        </ns1:Results>
```

My Response class have three properties : PackingSlipNo,VendorAccount,Vat

[image]

But I can't reach **008740774** value. How can I handle it?

DeliveryNumberType class:

```
public partial class DeliveryNumberType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string vendorAccountField;

        private string vatField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string VendorAccount {
            get {
                return this.vendorAccountField;
            }
            set {
                this.vendorAccountField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("VendorAccount");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Vat {
            get {
                return this.vatField;
            }
            set {
                this.vatField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Vat");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:

I think wsdl that given me is wrong. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504150/serialize-a-c-sharp-class-to-xml-with-attributes-and-a-single-value-for-the-clas)
it contains both simple and complex types.

Comment: The value is text.  But without know the method you are using to parse the xml I cannot help.

Comment: What jdweng said. 
Need to know how it is deserialized. Are you using a custom deserialisation or just classes, if classes, show us the code for your DeliveryNumber class.

Comment: I added DeliveryNumberType class in my question.