# c# - how to deserialize only part of xml file

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a xml:

```
     <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
        <identity category='store'
              type='file'
              name='HTTP File Upload' />
        <feature var='urn:xmpp:http:upload:0' />
        <x type='result' xmlns='jabber:x:data'>
            <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
                <value>urn:xmpp:http:upload:0</value>
            </field>
            <field var='max-file-size'>
                <value>5242880</value>
            </field>
        </x>
      </query>
```

I need to get data only from `<value>` tags. In a result I'd like to get `List<string>`.
How to do this using System.Xml.Serialization?

Thanks for help

Comment: What does “to get data only from tags” mean, and why must you use System.Xml.Serialization?

Comment: What would you like the result to look like?

Comment: i am sorry I used words in <> brackets and they weren't displayed. :) And I would like to see how it is done with XmlSerialization but i don't have to use it

Comment: You have deserialization as on of your tags but you have serialization in your question. I think you want serialization to serialize into C# class to get the XML attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Please do your own thorough research before posting a question. Here are a few methods, your XML has namespaces(Xmlns) too so you need to consider that, go to the source credit for more examples.

`- Method XML Namespace (you will most likely need this method)
    https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/113-c-reading-xml-with-namespace`

```
- Method XMLnode
`
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
doc.Load(Path);
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(...);
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["SuperString"].Value;
}
```

`

```
- Method Serialization
```

`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var title = new Title() { Id = 3, Value = "something" };
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Title));
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(stream, title);
            stream.Flush();
            Console.Write(new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(stream.GetBuffer())));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Title
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

}
`
```

Source Credit:
[Serialize a C# class to XML with attributes and a single value for the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504150/serialize-a-c-sharp-class-to-xml-) 
with-attributes-and-a-single-value-for-the-clas

[Read XML Attribute using XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933687/read-xml-attribute-using-) 
xmldocument

Answer (score 0):

Thanks *Deleted* for your response but I relized that I need data from `<field>` and `<value>`

```
     <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
         <value>urn:xmpp:http:upload:0</value>
```

Fortunetly I figured it out by myself:

```
    [XmlType("field")]
    public class Field
    {

        [XmlAttribute("var")]
        public string Var { get; set; }


        [XmlElement("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    [XmlType("query")]
    public class DiscoFileInfo
    {
        [XmlArray("x",Namespace = "jabber:x:data")]
        [XmlArrayItem("field", typeof(Field))]
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DiscoFileInfo), "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
```